# Number of 4-digit numbers that do not contain the digits $1, 2, 7$ and are divisible by $7$.

Tags: combinatorics

This is an elementary combinatorics problem.

I have discovered via computer generation that the answer is 294. This happens to be $(6 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7)/7$ which is the answer you'd naively expect to get if you simply counted all the numbers without those digits and divided the result by 7.

My question now is: why does this work? I thought the answer would be much more complicated than this and  that the remainders modulo 7 wouldn't cancel out exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the first three digits however you like to get $ABC*$  There are $6$ choices for the first, and $7$ each for the next two.   There is then exactly one choice for the units digit  $*$ which makes the expression divisible by $7$.  This is because the available digits $\{0,3,4,5,6,8,9\}$ are congruent to $\{0,3,4,5,6,1,2\}\pmod 7$ so we see that each residue class is represented exactly once.

Example:  Suppose you pick $333$ for the first three digits.  Then we remark that $3330\equiv 5\pmod 7$.  Now, the additive inverse of $5\pmod 7$ is $2$ and in our collection $2$ is represented by $9$.  Thus we must choose $9$ for the units place and we note that $3339$ is divisible by $7$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest number you can consider is 3000; the largest is 9999. If we consider numbers modulo 7, 3000 and 10000 are the same (we can consider the number following 9999 to be 3000). Therefore, we simply need to divide the total number of options by 7.